# org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException

Tags: mysql, mulesoft

Part of Mule 4 training I am trying to connect MySQL database and getting error...

org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: Could not obtain connection from data source
org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: Could not obtain connection from data source
Caused by: org.mule.extension.db.api.exception.connection.ConnectionCreationException: Could not obtain connection from data source
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:mysql://mudb.learn.mulesoft.com:3306/training?logger=org.mule.extension.db.api.logger.MuleMySqlLogger$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$42140f7b : Access denied for user 'mule'@'cpe-104-139-120-137.carolina.res.rr.com' (using password: YES)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:mysql://mudb.learn.mulesoft.com:3306/training?logger=org.mule.extension.db.api.logger.MuleMySqlLogger$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$42140f7b : Access denied for user 'mule'@'cpe-104-139-120-137.carolina.res.rr.com' (using password: YES)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftula.png)

let me know what else I need to change for a successful connection.

Answer (score 0):

The root error is:

```
Access denied for user 'mule'@'cpe-104-139-120-137.carolina.res.rr.com'
```

It looks like nothing is wrong in the Mule application. You need to fix the password or the permissions for that user in the MySql database.

This [article](https://www.linuxcloudvps.com/blog/how-to-fix-access-denied-errors-in-mysql/) can be helpful to troubleshoot that.

Comment: I was following the training doc provided my Mulesoft. I don't have any exposure to the permissions on database end.   Training link to connect db https://training.mulesoft.com/site/coursePlayer.do?dispatch=show&courseSessionId=d81fd27d-97c3-11ea-9f48-0cc47adeb5f8

Comment: you have a point. The password is incorrect. Issue is resolved.